# Xml node reading for each loop

Tags: c#, xml, loops, foreach, nodes

I am trying to loop through an Xml file and display the value for account in a message.

```
XmlNodeList nodeList = testDoc.SelectNodes("/details/row/var");
foreach (XmlNode no in nodeList)
{
   XmlNode node = testDoc.SelectSingleNode("/details/row/var[@name='account']");
   test.actual = node.Attributes["value"].Value;

   MessageBox.Show(test.account);
 }
```

The message box is currently displaying the first record repeatidly, how can I get to the next record?

Thanks for your input in advance.

Comment: You are not using the no variable which is the value from each iteration would be one starting point

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are repeatedly assigning `node` with the same element from `testDoc`. It is not clear what `test.account` is (perhaps a mistype for `test.actual`)?

`no` is the variable which will iterate the contents of `nodeList` - I imagine you intended to use that.

**EDIT** following edit of OP
Now you've shown us what nodeList is, I suspect you want to do something like this instead :

```
XmlNodeList nodeList = testDoc.SelectNodes("/details/row/var[@name='account']"); 
foreach (XmlNode no in nodeList) 
{    
   test.actual = no.Attributes["value"].Value;
   ...
```

Answer (score 5):

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("d:\\test.xml");
        XmlNodeList node = doc.GetElementsByTagName("w:r");
        foreach (XmlNode xn in node)
        {
            try
            {
                if (xn["w:t"].InnerText != null)
                {
                    if (xn["w:t"].InnerText == "#")
                    {
                        string placeHolder = xn["w:t"].InnerText;
                        foreach (XmlNode a in node)
                        { 
                            if (a["w:t"].InnerText != "#")
                            {
                                string placeHolder1 = a["w:t"].InnerText;
                            }
                        } 
                    }
                }
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Write(e);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the sample for parent node value to get information of the child nodes.here i am using the ReportItems ParentNode and Print only image child nodes.

```
        xmldoc.Load(rdlFile);
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        XmlNode node = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("ReportItems")[0];
        XmlNodeList list = node.ChildNodes;
        atributes=new string[node.ChildNodes.Count];
        int  l = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < node.ChildNodes.Count; j++)
        {


            if (list[j].Name == "Image")
            {
                XmlAttributeCollection att = list[j].Attributes;
                atributes[l] = att[0].Value.ToUpper();

            }
            l++;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < node.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
        {
            if (searchText.Text.ToUpper() == atributes[i])
            {
                XmlNodeList lastlist = node.ChildNodes;
                XmlNodeList endlist = lastlist[i].ChildNodes;
                for (int k = 0; k < endlist.Count; k++)
                {
                    sb.Append(endlist[k].Name+" - "+ endlist[k].InnerText);
                    sb.Append("\n"+"\n");
                }

            }

        }
```

let me know if you have doubt..

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XDocument();

xdoc.Load("*/File/*"); 
string xmlcontents = xdoc.InnerXml;

var xpath = "(/details/row/var[@name='account'])";

XmlNodeList lists = xdoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes(xpath);

foreach (XmlNode _node in lists)
{
    string _nodeValue = _node.InnerText;
    MessageBox.Show(_nodeValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
        //Create an xml reader;
        XmlDocument _xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        _xmlDocument.Load(/*File Name here*/);

        //Select the element with in the xml you wish to extract;
        XmlNodeList _nodeList = _xmlDocument.SelectNodes("/details/row/var[@name='account']");

        //Display the values in the node list to the screen;
        foreach (XmlNode _node in _nodeList)
        {
            String _nodeValue = _node.InnerText.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(_nodeValue.ToString());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but you may need to use recursion.  If not, it should just look like this:

```
XmlDocument doc = //etc..
foreach(XmlNode node in doc.ChildNodes)
{
    if(node.Name == "account")
    {
        MessageBox.Show(node.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I needed to read whole post carefully... edit so I can undo -1. Also I still see no reason why OP would use recursion - XPath already selects nodes as deep as one wants...

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't spend time with reading the xml node by node. Try [Deserialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsh84875.aspx):

Comment: -1 : That depends entirely on what the XML infoset looks like and what he's trying to do with it. Deserializing to a type may be loads of unnecessary work both at design time and runtime, or might not even be possible.

Comment: @Chris ~ best practice is always better than any other practice. Just wanted the OP to know that *Deserialization* does exists. If I was asking this question, I would mention that I am not interested in Deserialization since the xml is way too complex and I just need a small part which he didn't.